# Call ajax from dynamic generated tag and fetch value from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have fetched data from ajax like

**UPDATE**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('id', tr_job_room);
a.setAttribute('onclick', 'getGroupsData(this.id)');                 
var audioLength;
var ul_ul_li_a = document.createElement('a');
ul_ul_li_a.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-toggle');
ul_ul_li_a.setAttribute('href', '#');
ul_ul_li_a.innerHTML = "Audios";
ul_ul_li_a.setAttribute('id', tr_job_room);
if (audioLength > 0) {
    alert("audiolength"+audioLength);
    $(ul_ul_li_a).on('click', function () {
       alert(audioLength+"sdasds");
       varid = this.id;
       audiosPlay(varid);
       scriptpanel();
       getTxtData();
    });
 }
```

and ajax is:

```
// DISPLAY GROUPS DATA
function getGroupsData(arg) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("getGroupsData")',
        dataType: "json",
        mtype: "post",
        data: { arg: arg },
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            audioLengh = data.groups[0].audio.length;
            audioDisplay(arg, data.groups[0].audio.length, data.groups[0].audio);
        }
    });
}
```

Is this the correct way to fetch data?
I am not getting audioLength value in `if` block
Any suggestion?

Comment: can you please take the time to format/indent your code properly before you post it, next time around?

Comment: Where are you calling getGroupsData? Because AJAX is asynchronous my guess would be that you're not getting a response by the time the `if` block is reached.

Comment: It looks to me like all of the coding starting with `var audioLength;` and after should be in the `success()` function of the ajax call.

Comment: @jwatts1980 then how can I fetch data of ajax in if block?

Comment: I think your code is not in the correct order. The problem is that I can't tell what order it is supposed to be in. Can you please explain, step by step, what is supposed to be happening?

Comment: @jwatts1980 sure This is basic structure http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/ougyu0f2/4/ when I click on air I called ajax that is getgroups data and from that I want to do that if audioLength is >0 then call other function otherwise not.

Comment: Deb, okay let me see if I undertand: When "Air" is clicked, it has to make an AJAX request to get the groups. Then when "Audios" is clicked, it has to execute a function only if `audioLength` is greater than 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76269/discussion-between-deb-and-jwatts1980).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `if` into the click event. Execute the function no matter what, but put the if statement into the function to determine if any of the other functions should run:

```
$(ul_ul_li_a).on('click', function () {
    alert("audiolength"+audioLength);

    if (audioLength > 0) {
        alert(audioLength+"sdasds");
        varid = this.id;
        audiosPlay(varid);
        scriptpanel();
        getTxtData();
    }
});
```

I can't tell from your code, but if you are dynamically generating the sub-list under "Air", then you may need to change the line with `on` to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.dropdown-toggle', function () {
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the in the `success` function, your variable is spelled `audioLengh` instead of `audioLength`.

Comment: @Deb have you tried putting in an `error: function() { ... }` function to make sure that the AJAX call is not failing?

Comment: same alert undefined..AJAX is not falling because alert of success is show value of audiolength but can not get value in `if` block

Comment: @Deb Are you creating the "Audios" link in the AJAX success function?

Comment: *No it is `$(ul_ul_li_a)` innerHTML set to AUDIOS

Comment: @Deb is `var audioLength;` inside of a function? Maybe it is a scoping issue.

Comment: No it is out side of function

Comment: @Deb I am sorry, but your example code is not complete enough for me to understand the problem. It seems you are posting snippets of the code, and I think the problem is a small one, but I cannot see it with the examples you have provided.

Comment: Onclick of air I want to fetch data from ajax which must return value of audioLength and then want to check if greater then call other function

Comment: You can tell me your own way to do so I have just tried but not successed by doing this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76270/discussion-between-deb-and-jwatts1980).